# How to add navigation icon to embeded Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, embed, navigationbar

I have an embeded `Google Maps` on my website. If I check it from mobile I can't find *navigate here* or something like this function or icon.

I used the standard embed code from [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/). Like this one:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zV4QqQ0y5KZs.kCBlZMtOp0FA" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

It is possible to add this icon or button or something like this? Of course I want to show this feature only on mobile devices.

Comment: You can implement it yourself using the Google Maps Javascript API v3.

Comment: @geocodezip: Can you give me an example code or an exact url to solve this question?

Comment: By _navigate here_, do you mean that from your current location you will be given directions to that point which you have specified?